# Is updating a .resx file as an editor possible in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, localization, resource-files, resources, resx

Is there a recommended way to update existing .resx files as an editor?

.resx files are the common way to provide localized texts.

As an editor it should be possible to change those texts without accessing files on the file system and without requesting a new solution version (which means .resx file is updated by developers or administrators).

Is that possible out of the box? If not, what would be a good solution?

Answer (score 2):

How do you mean?

Most of the resources files can be found under `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Resources`, and hence can be altered without deploying a solution. But it is probably wise to update your resources also in your solution, to prevent it from overwriting your changes on the next deploy

Comment: Edited my question. Forgot to mention, that sharepoint users / editors should be able to update the localized texts

Comment: There is no OOTB functionality for that

Comment: Worth noting that some of the .resx are copied to the inetpub folder, and after you edit one of these files you may need to run psconfig to perform this copy (which is the easiest way to ensure you copy it to the right place). Downside is that psconfig does an iisreset.